# diff ignore certain pattern in the file

Tags: diff

I want to make diff between two files which contains lines beginning with "line_$NR". I want to make diff between the files making abstraction of the presence of "lines_$NR" but when the differences are printed I want lines_$NR to be displayed. 
It is possible to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case, you have to preprocess your iput files to remove `/^line_[0-9]*/`, diff the resulting files, then recombine the diff output with the removed words according to line numbers in diff output.

Python's `difflib` should be very handy here, or same from perl. If you want to stick to shell, I suppose you could get by with awk.

If you don't need exact output, perhaps you can use diff's `--line-format=...` directive to inject actual line number in a diff, rather than the word you removed in preprocessing step.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood your question